# Ошибка при старте проекта используя symfony 4 Exceptions : No route found for "GET /"

Tags: php, symfony

Изучая framework symfony 4 столкнулся с проблемой.На старте после настройки и запуска **server:run** встречаю стандартное окно запуска symfony 4.Но, с одним большим Но.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А зайдя глубже наблюдаю вот такую картину:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Убил сутки на разгадку этой тайны.Наткнулся на данную публикациюю [No route found for "GET /" error with Symfony 4.](https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/589)Но так и не получилась.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос был решён путём внесения изменений **routes.yaml** с указанием маршрута выполнения.*Например:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обсуждение вопроса, [о данной проблеме на git](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/26041).